# MySQL: Combine two rows into one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

How do I combine two rows from the same table into one row to avoid null fields? For example, if I have the following two rows:

```
id col1 col2 col3
 1   12   null 13  
 2   56   74   89
```

I want to get the result:

```
1 12 74 13
```

In another words, I want the values from the row with the id = 1 but if it has `null` values, I want to replace those `null`s with corresponding values from the row with id = 2. I guess another constraint is that number of columns in this table is large so I would want to avoid listing the individual columns. Is this at all possible with MySQL?

Comment: it does not make real sense how or why are these records related to be merged what if you also have records with id 3 , 4 , 5 and 6.... end so on..

Comment: @RaymondNijland This is just an example but you can think that row 2 is a set of default values whereas row 1 is value for individual user...if the user doesn't have value, we plug in the default value

Comment: fair enough but i think ideally your question is more about how to merge records with odd and even id's to merge as one record, right ?  What should the results be with more records can you add that case aswell as two records example data is a bit to little to get a good feeling for your user case...

Comment: I'm with Raymond here. Please add more rows to your example and give us a rule how to find a default row for any other row (like what makes you choose row 2 as a default for row 1?).

Comment: This is highly symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry to be confusing but it's a very simple example...row 2 default for all the rows. So if I typed out another 1000 example rows, row 2 would be  considered the default for all 1000.

Comment: *"row 2 default for all the rows. So if I typed out another 1000 example rows, row 2 would be considered the default for all 1000. "* i wonder if that when row 2 has default values for all the rows, why that record is even in the table ... consider using [datatype column defaults](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) instead like `col2 INT DEFAULT 74` and remove that default record..

Comment: *"Please understand this was a simple example just to illustrate the problem I was having. In larger context of the application I am working on"* You are leaving out details with over-simplification making it harder to suggest something solid you have to understand that.. In that case `SELECT coalesce(your_table.col1, defualt.col1), [, ...] FROM (SELECT  2 AS id   56 AS col1, 74 AS col2, 89 AS col3) AS default CROSS JOIN your_table)` would /should make more sense to use when you need to have a dynamic default row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `left join`:

```
select coalesce(t.col1, t2.col1) as col1,
       coalesce(t.col2, t2.col2) as col2,
       coalesce(t.col3, t2.col3) as col3       
from t left join
     t t2
     on t2.id = 2
where t.id = 1
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid listing the columns ?

Comment: @Gdgames Gamers: No. But what's the problem with that?

Comment: @GdgamesGamers . . . I don't think so.